# How to display the names of different dictionaries in a combobox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter

How can I display the names John, Linda, Martin in the combobox? They would serve me exactly as I wrote with 3 different dictionaries and not with the three names entered in a single dictionary.

I don't want to click on any buttons, but see the names directly as soon as I open the app. Thank you

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()  
window.attributes('-zoomed', True)
window.configure(bg='#f3f2f2')

style = ttk.Style(window)
style.theme_use('clam')

John = {"Name": John, "Years": 1980}
Linda = {"Name": Linda, "Years": 1983}
Martin = {"Name": Martin, "Years": 1981}

all_name=ttk.Combobox(window, width = 8)
all_name.place(x=5, y=60)
all_name['value'] = ["aaaa"]
all_name.set("All Name")


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `all_name['value'] = [x["Name"] for x in [John, Linda, Martin]]`.

Comment: @acw1668 With your suggestion, i get this error: NameError: name 'John' is not defined. Do you have any other ideas? Thank you

Comment: As the answer said `{"Name": John, ...}` should be `{"Name": "John", ...}`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you. If you want you can write an answer so I vote you and I accept your answer. Also could you help me with this question too? It's the same code as this question

Answer (score 0):

You should do list comprehension to get the names from your dictionaries. The below implementation put the dictionaries into one list and the `x` is the loop variable and the `x["Name"]` puts the value of `Name` key to the "result" list. You can read more about [list comprehension on this site](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/).

```
all_name['value'] = [x["Name"] for x in [John, Linda, Martin]]
```

**Note:**

- The value of "Name" key also should be `str` type. Your current implementation throws `NameError: name 'John' is not defined` exception if the value is not string. Eg.: `John = {"Name": "John", "Years": 1980}`